# Is this implementation of signed URLs reasonably secure?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, hmac, signing

I'm trying to implement signed URLs for short lived access to static files.
The idea is:

- generate an URL with an expiration timestamp (e.g. `https://example.com/file.png?download=false&expires=1586852158`)
- sign it with HMACSHA256 and a shared secret and append the signature at the end of URL (e.g. `https://example.com/file.png?download=false&expires=1586852158&signature=6635ea14baeeaaffe71333cf6c7fa1f0af9f6cd1a17abb4e75ca275dec5906d1`

When i receive the request on the server, I take out the `signature` parameter and verify that the rest of the URL signed with HMACSHA256 and the same shared secret results in the same signature.

The implementation is as follows:

```cs
    public static class URLSigner
    {
        private static string GetSignatureForUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key);
            var signature = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri));
            var hexSignature = BitConverter.ToString(signature).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
            return hexSignature;
        }

        public static string SignUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var hexSignature = GetSignatureForUri(uri, key);
            return QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "signature", hexSignature }});
        }

        public static bool VerifyUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var signatureRegex = "[\\?&]signature=([a-z0-9]+)$";
            var signatureMatch = Regex.Match(uri, signatureRegex);
            if (!signatureMatch.Success || signatureMatch.Groups.Count != 2)
                return false;
            var parsedSignature = signatureMatch.Groups[1].Value;

            var originalUri = Regex.Replace(uri, signatureRegex, "");
            var hexSignature = GetSignatureForUri(originalUri, key);
            return hexSignature == parsedSignature;
        }
    }
```

and it's used like so:

```cs
var signedUri = URLSigner.SignUri("https://example.com/file.png?download=false", secretKey);
var isVerified = URLSigner.VerifyUri(signedUri, secretKey);
```

Is this implementation of signed URLs reasonably secure?

Comment: You're likely to get a better response at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation seems to be missing the verification of the expiration time, so any one key would currently work indefinitely.

Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong with this approach in general. You may want to add in a key beyond just the timestamp for identifying the user or request in some way though.

Here's a good article on how the general approach is used for one time passwords which is essentially what you are doing.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-time-based-one-time-passwords-work-and-why-you-should-use-them-in-your-app-fdd2b9ed43c3/

Comment: Oh yeah, the verification of the `expires` parameter is validated in the request handler. Here I'm just making sure the signing is done correctly and verified correctly.
With regards to identifying the user, I don't need that at the moment. The signed link is given out only after all authorisation checks have been validated in a separate request to the API.
Thanks for the article :)

Comment: Verifying the datetime should be part of that signature process otherwise you can just pass in the current datetime but use an old token if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, assuming the URL is verified, then the datetime is verified to be correct. In other words if you were to take a valid signed URL and change the `expires` parameter then the validation would fail because the signature would change. Also I see signing and verifying the lifetime to be two orthogonal things.

Comment: @ShoeDiamente in most/all JWT implementations, the verification of the timestamp is done in the verification step of the token. Your token verification of the URI only is verifying the timestamp hasn't changed, not that the timestamp is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is secure, as long as the key is treated properly. The hash should be able to ensure data integrity (data in URL are not modified by other people).

Perhaps, one little improvement is to `dispose` the `HMACSHA256` object (maybe by `using`), but that may not be related to security.

Answer (score 0):

I have one concern. You are saying you want to use **HMACSHA256** and a **private key**, but in security terminology what you're passing to the HMAC is not a *private key*, it's a *shared secret*.

If you have to had a public, private key for your sign and verify authentication, I would suggest using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. With RSA you have two keys, public key and private key.

Your client creates a private key and keep it and give its public key to the server. So only client can sign and anyone with public key can verify it.

On another note, no matter what algorithm you ended up using, I would suggest to add the signature to a authorization header instead of query string. This is more common and you don't need to match a regex in each request.

Comment: Yeah, bad terminology on my part. I meant shared secret. These signed URLs are given out in order to give access to static files like PDFs, images or other. These files are more commonly used in HTML links and/or `<img>` and other tags that don't easily support making requests with specific authorization headers (in that case I'd probably use the existing authorization mechanism with a bearer token).